# JSF datatable hide column border if column is not displayed(rendered)

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a JSF data table

```
 <h:dataTable id="memberTable" value="#{bean.pList}" border="0" 
rowClasses="rowEven rowOdd" var="item">
<h:column rendered="#{item.isDisplay == Y}">
<h:outputText value="#{item.visitDate}" >
</h:outputText>
</h:column>
</datatable>
```

I have more such columns that are rendred based on a condition, when the condition is false and if I have the border=1; I see that blank cells are displayed. How can i display only the columns i want and have other ie. rendered=false not display blank cells?

Thanks,
Sai.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't render an entire column based on the condition of a particular row. This makes technically no sense. You need to evaluate the condition based on a property of the parent bean.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.pList}" var="item">
    <h:column rendered="#{bean.display == 'Y'}">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.visitDate}" />
    </h:column>
</datatable>
```

Move the `public String getDisplay()` method to the class behind `#{bean}`.

Note that I also fixed some other mistakes in your EL expression. You shouldn't prefix the property name with `is` or `get` and you should quote string values. You can also better make it a boolean property.

```
private boolean display;

public boolean isDisplay() {
    return display;
}
```

with

```
rendered="#{bean.display}"
```