# Column header not visible when column is conditionally rendered

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a `h:dataTable`. I would like to render a row conditionally as follows:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myController.entities}" var="entity">
 <h:column rendered="#{entity.selected}">
  <f:facet name="header">
   <h:outputText value="header" />
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{entity.name}" />
 </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

In my controller there is variable `List <Entity>` entities which has getters and setters.

`Entity` class contains two variables : `boolean selected` and `String name` with its getters and setters.

When `#{entity.selected}` is false, then the row is hidden. When `#{entity.selected}` is true, then the row is shown, **but without header**. When I do not use the rendered attribute on the column my header becomes visible.

This question is similar to [p:column header facet is not shown when rendered attribute is used on p:column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948799/pcolumn-header-facet-is-not-shown-when-rendered-attribute-is-used-on-pcolumn)

But none of the solution given works for me and Iam not using primefaces.

Can somebody help me with this? Iam new to JSF and the mistake might be something silly and fix fairly easy, but please help me figure it out. Thanks.

Iam posting the outputs that I get when I tried the above code.

```
**Header**

name 0

name 1

name 2

name 3

name 4
```

This output shows the datatable using simply `<h:column>` without trying to render it conditionally. The header can be seen.

Now when I use conditional rendering:

```
name 1

name 3
```

In this output Iam trying to use conditional rendering `<h:column rendered="#{entity.selected}">`. As you can see that for "name 0", "name 3" and "name 5" the `#{entity.selected}` is false and hence its not rendering.
This is exactly what I need but only if the header shows up.

I want to render my **row** invisible where the `#{entity.selected}` value is false. Also show the column header. Can this be possible?

Comment: Why are you trying to render a **whole** column conditionally based on a property of a *single* row? How about other rows? How does this technically make sense? Shouldn't you instead the condition in `#{myController}` instead?

Comment: Related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208721/jsf-datatable-hide-column-border-if-column-is-not-displayedrendered/11208832#11208832 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982720/pcolumn-rendered-attribute-does-not-seem-to-work-with-logical-operators/16982840#16982840

Comment: Thank a lot BaluC for responding. You are correct of course. Its not the column I want not to render its the entire row. Being fairly new to JSF and datatables and also my datatable having just one column, got me confused. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the `rendered` condition on the **cell**, not on the **column**.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myController.entities}" var="entity">
 <h:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
   <h:outputText value="header" />
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{entity.name}" rendered="#{entity.selected}" />
 </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Or, if you've multiple components or plain text representing cell content, wrap it in a `<h:panelGroup>` or `<ui:fragment>`.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myController.entities}" var="entity">
 <h:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
   header
  </f:facet>
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{entity.selected}">
   Blah blah #{entity.name} blah blah
  </h:panelGroup>
 </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

*(note: you don't necessarily need `h:outputText` over all place, see also [Is it suggested to use h:outputText for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539894/is-it-suggested-to-use-houtputtext-for-everything/))*

Apply if necessary the following CSS on the table to hide empty cells in case you've applied e.g. borders or bgcolors on table cells:

```
table {
    empty-cells: hide;
}
```

A completely different alternative is to provide a new model which contains *only* the desired entities:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myController.selectedEntities}" var="entity">
 <h:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
   header
  </f:facet>
  #{entity.name}
 </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: Perfect! The css part did the trick. Thanks a lot BaluC!! I would have liked to give +1 as well, not enough reputation though :)

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
...
    <f:facet name="header">
       <h:outputText value="header" />
      </f:facet>
...
```

try simply

```
...
    <f:facet name="header">Header</f:facet>
...
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Thanks for the response though Jas.